# What do curly braces mean in JSX (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

For an example, to set a style in react you could do

`var css = {color: red}`

and

`<h1 style={css}>Hello world</h1>`

Why do you need the curly braces around css in the second code snippet?

Comment: <h1 style={{color: 'red'}}>Hello world</h1>

Comment: Official docs on [Embedding Expressions in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)

Comment: How can I setAttribute in react for a tag as "attribute={value}", because `tag.setAttribute('attribute','{value}')` does `<tag attribute="{value}"` and I need `<tag attribute={value}`. Any solution ???

Answer (score 73):

The curly braces are a special syntax to let the JSX parser know that it needs to interpret the contents in between them as JavaScript instead of a string.

You need them when you want to use a JavaScript expression like a variable or a reference inside JSX. Because if you use the standard double quote syntax like so:

`var css = { color: red }`

`<h1 style="css">Hello world</h1>`

JSX doesn't know you meant to use the variable `css` in the style attribute instead of the string. And by placing the curly braces around the variable `css`, you are telling the parser "take the contents of the variable `css` and put them here". (Technically its evaluating the content)

This process is generally referred to as "interpolation".

Comment: So why doesn't it just interpret the lack of quotation marks to mean it's not a string, like the rest of JavaScript does?

Comment: Because that's how JSX is setup and how its parser works. `<h1 style={css}>` is not technically JavaScript. It's JSX and its syntax calls for curly braces when you want to use a JS expression in JSX.

Comment: Perfect example. As a quick reminder: first curly bracket i.e "{ **css** }" means evaluate the **css** variable / content. When a second curly bracket is present i.e "{ **{color: red}** }", it means **{color: red}** is a json (JavaScript object).

Answer (score 27):

If you don't use the variable `css`, the JSX could look like this:

`<h1 style={ {color: 'red'} }>Hello world</h1>`

I guess you are confused about the double curly braces.

so you know that the curly braces in JSX means `process the inner value in JavaScript`, so the outer braces is used exactly for this purpose.

But the `style` property accepts an `object`. And an object also needs another pair of curly braces to wrap it up. That's the purpose for the inner ones.

Answer (score 6):

The outer curly braces tell the JSX parser that the syntax should be interpreted as javascript. The inner braces are used because the style variable accepts an object.

let's break this down:

```
<h1 style={interpret javascritp {interpret the object} }> hello </h1>
```

Answer (score 4):

You put curly braces when you want to use the value of a variable inside "html" (so inside the render part). It's just a way of telling the app to take the value of the variable and put it there, as opposed to a word.

Comment: What do you mean by "as opposed to a word"? Do you mean as opposed to a string?

Comment: @KyleDelaney If you do 56+4, it will render 56+4, but if you enclose it in curly braces as {56+4}, it will render 60.

Comment: A weird but practical thing is that curly brace expressions that yield boolean values render nothing, unless they represent a tag attribute. This is useful for writing `{someBooleanVariable || <SomeTag/>}` to conditionally render a tag, but it is maybe not immediately obvious that {1} renders a number but {true} renders nothing. I have unsuccessfully tried to find where this distinction of how different result types are rendered (or not) is documented.