# Self invoking function in react js ? (as in regular javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to invoke the `function good` without calling it from a event. It should run as soon as page opened just like in the `self invoking javascript function`.
[Here is an example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_invoke_function)

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

   good(){
      console.log('I was triggered during good')
   }

   render() {
       console.log('I was triggered during render')
       return(
          <div>
             good();  
          </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5):

Few Points:

**1.** You need to use `this` keyword to call any function from any other function.

**2.** To put `js` code inside `JSX`, we need to use `{}`.

Write it like this:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

    good(){
        console.log('I was triggered during good')
        return <div> Hello </div>
    }

    render() {
        console.log('I was triggered during render')
        return(
            <div>
                {this.good()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Check React DOC: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Check these answers for more details:

[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

[What do curly braces mean in JSX (React)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904825/what-do-curly-braces-mean-in-jsx-react)

Comment: Nicely explained... :)

Comment: That really helped

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lifecycle methods as componentDidMount(){} or componentWillMount(){}.

componentWillMount will be triggered before mounting of component and componentDidMount() will be triggered after component has been mounted.

Comment: Thanks. I will be trying those.