# Passing a function to child component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a simplified example of what I am trying to do.  What I wanted to be able to do is to pass the functions to different components of React via props.  I can pass text to props, and call the function directly by doing `<button onClick={popup}>` but that is not the purpose of my experiment. The onClick doesn't trigger the function, and there is 'uncaught' error in console.log when rendering which is not helpful.

```
const Elem = (props) =>{ 
  return (<div>
    <h1> hi {props.name} {props.last} phase two </h1>
    <button onClick={props.clickon}> {props.text} </button>
      </div>
  );
};

function popup(){  
  alert("It works!")
}

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
 }
  render(){return (<Elem name = 'paul' last='shreeman' clickon='popup' text='PushMe'/>
  )
}}

ReactDOM.render(
<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Here's the link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/pkshreeman/pen/GENmaG?editors=0010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is, you are not passing the `function` you are passing a string, to pass a `function` you need to write it like this:

```
clickon = {popup}
```

Now it will pass the `function popup`, not the `string "popup"`.

Full code:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
    }

    render(){
         return (
             <Elem name='paul' last='shreeman' clickon={popup} text='PushMe'/>
         )
    }
}
```

Check the working code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MobvqB?editors=0010

Check this answer for details about **what's the meaning of `{}`**:

[What do curly braces mean in JSX (React)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904825/what-do-curly-braces-mean-in-jsx-react)