# I get confused about the usage of {} and cannot distinguish when it is a JavaScript thing when it is react native thing (i mean JSX)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am learning `react native` and `ES6`. I read many documents but sometimes get confused with the code. for instance, here:

```
return (
      <View {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}>
        {this.renderCards()}
      </View>
    );
```

I know that `...` is gonna open the object and spread it as the `View` props, but why do we need to wrap with `{}`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do curly braces mean in JSX (React)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904825/what-do-curly-braces-mean-in-jsx-react)

Comment: @DavidRawson: The other question is about a different set of `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces are a special syntax to let the JSX parser know that it needs to interpret the contents in between them as JavaScript instead of a string.

You need them when you want to use a JavaScript expression like a variable or a reference inside JSX.

Portion copied from an answer to "[What do curly braces mean in JSX (React)? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43904857/1026017)", by [Daniel Sandiego](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3638649/daniel-sandiego).

Comment: Just a link to another question or answer is insufficient with respect to the requirement for attribution under [CC BY-SA 3.0](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), the license under which all user contributed content on Stack Exchange is distributed. You need something like: 'The following is from an answer to "[What do curly braces mean in JSX (React)? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43904857)", by [Daniel Sandiego](/users/3638649/daniel-sandiego), copyright 2017, licensed under [CC BY-SA 3.0](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)'.

Answer (score 0):

> but why do we need to wrap with `{}`

It was simply decided that "spread props" need to be encapsulated in `{}`. As far as I remember, there wasn't a technical reason for that decision.

FWIW, I was in favor of omitting them.

---

In general whenever you are in a JSX context, `{ }` is part of JSX. You can also have a look at the syntax spec here: https://facebook.github.io/jsx/