# Key is unique but still getting "Encountered two children with the same key"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following data:

```
const huntersData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'A',
        image: '',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'B',
        image: '',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'C',
        image: '',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'D',
        image: '',
    }
]

export default huntersData
```

and the following component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Hunters(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                props.hunters.map(hunter => (
                    <div key="{hunter.id}" onClick={() => props.selectHunter(hunter)}>
                        <img src={hunter.image} alt={hunter.name} height="90" />
                        <p>{hunter.name}</p>
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

and call it with:

```
<Hunters
    hunters={this.state.hunters}
    selectedHunter={this.state.selectedHunter}
    selectHunter={this.selectHunter}
/>
```

but I get the following error:
`Encountered two children with the same key, {hunter.id}.` I even tried with using `index` as key but still getting the same error. The keys are unique according to the data object, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do curly braces mean in JSX (React)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904825/what-do-curly-braces-mean-in-jsx-react)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You used a string literal `"{hunter.id}"` which is always the same. You need to use the actual id as the key:

```
key={hunter.id}
```

If you intended to use a format string the correct syntax would be:

```
key={`${hunter.id}`}
```

but this is not required here as the key is just consisting of the id itself.

Comment: That was so stupid of me, thanks! I will accept the offer when I'm allowed to.