# Two classes on single react HTML element

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs

I feel like there is a simple answer here, but I'm not finding it -

In my react header I import my stylesheet under 'styles' and as such refers to css classes as

```
<div className={styles.selectorname}>
```

But I can't figure out, with this notation, how to declare multiple styles on one element. Example that doesn't work:

```
<div className={styles.selectorname1} {styles.selectorname2}>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `className={{styles. selectorname1, styles.selectorname2}}` doesn't work?

Comment: Does not, sadly

Comment: You can't do this with classes. You have to use the `styles` attribute along with spread syntax to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are class names, then you can do with template strings (``)

```
<div className={`${styles.selectorname1} ${styles.selectorname2}`}>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use spread operator to combine different style objects. For an example, let's have a look at this css file which has few declarations.

```
.myColor {
  color: DodgerBlue;
}

.myFont {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}
```

We can combine these using the following syntax.

```
<div style={{...styles.myColor, ...styles.myFont}}>
```

Similarily, you can use the following code to combine those styles. The styles can be from two different files as well.

```
<div style={{...styles.selectorname1, ...styles.selectorname2}}>
```

Note: The `...` which we are using is called spread operator. Read more on spread syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you used quotes ?
Like such as :

```
<div className="{styles.selectorname1} {styles.selectorname2}">
```

Comment: This won't work. `"{styles.selectorname1} {styles.selectorname2}"` is a string. You're not embedding those values into the string. To embed the value, you can use a string literal.

Comment: In `jsx` syntax, curly braces (`{` `}`) are used when providing an expression or a reference, while single/double quotes (`"` or `'`) are used when providing a string directly. (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43904857/7216508))

Comment: Amit, you can't use two CSS class without quotes on a SGML and HTML. You must delimite classes if you want to combine. 
https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2