# Can't figure out the behaviour of curly braces and props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compiler-errors

This is the portion of code through which I was playing

```
function Give({need}){
  let type1={need===true?'chemist':'others'}
  let type2={need}===true?'chemist':'others'
}
```

I read that 
[The curly braces are a special syntax to let the JSX parser know that it needs to interpret the contents in between them as JavaScript instead of a string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904825/what-do-curly-braces-mean-in-jsx-react)
So I was expecting both of these to work but only the second one is working even though inside brace in type1 I have javascript expression. I got this error, what does it even mean??

```
/App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (4:17)

  2 | ....
  3 | function Give({need}){
> 4 |   let type1={need===true?'chemist':'others'}
    |                 ^
  5 |   let type2={need}===true?'chemist':'others'
  6 | }
```

Can someone please help with the reason for this behavior?

Comment: The code in your function is not JSX, it's plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a Javascript question rather than a react question tho.

Nonetheless on the `Give()` function, you are receiving a parameter that you are destructuring by typing `{need}` so that object must have a property named "need", so now that you are destructuring, need should be used directly like another answer here:

opt 1: `let type = need===true?'chemist':'others'`

opt 2: `let type = need ? 'chemist':'others'` (this one works like this because you know that need is a boolean)

Here's a useful link to know a little bit more about this:

[destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
[ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)

Answer (score 0):

`{need}` is destrucing
and `let type={need===true?'chemist':'others'}` is an invalid condition
it could be someting like `let type = need===true?'chemist':'others'` or moreover `let type = need ? 'chemist':'others'`

please checkout how javascript works. none of these are react things.